# Windows 7: Homegroup Connectivity

Tags: windows-7, homegroup

It seems that no matter what I do, I cannot get my two computers to work together and join the same Homegroup.

The computers in question:

- Desktop with Win7 Ultimate x64 connected via Wireless Connection
- Netbook with Win7 Home Pro (32 bit) connected via Wireless Connection

Other items:

- Both show the same network connection, connected through the same wireless router (Linksys WRT310N)
- Both are set to Home Network in Windows
- I can see both machines browsing through the Network Viewer in Windows Explorer
- Disabling the firewall on both machines has no effect on the Homegroup Feature
- Both are using the fully patched RTM version of Windows 7

Does anyone have any ideas? Is there anything else I can test with? Everything I read seems to imply that I should be good to go. Is this a 64bit issue?

What really bothers me is that this would be such a handy feature to have working since the netbook doesn't store much, and the desktop has all of my music/pic/docs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the solution was to replace the Wireless adapter on my Win7 x64 machine. Now everything works great.

Thank you to all who read/responded!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a homegroup with your desktop (ultimate) first, if you haven't do it yet [Start > User Name > Left Sidebar > Homegroup], the you will need to select the folders you want to share.

After that, in your netbook you do the same steps but with the difference that it would show your newly created homegroup in your desktop computer. Then you only select what folders/libraries you want to browse and *voilá*.

Comment: Ahh - if only it was that easy. That is the exact approach I took. Unfortunately the netbook doesn't see the homegroup to join.

Comment: You can check here: http://crave.cnet.co.uk/software/0,39029471,49303968,00.htm

Maybe it's the network discovery.

Comment: I have checked the network discovery and that doesn't seem to be an issue. Is there anything lower level that I can use to test this (i.e. telnet or something)?